# Where can I find a public version of the XFS specification document for ATM cash dispensers?

Tags: specifications, xfs, cen-xfs

I am working on a software that interacts with the cash dispenser of an ATM. I was referred to an XFS specification document, but the [link](https://www.cen.eu/work/areas/ICT/eBusiness/Pages/CWA13449.aspx) is broken.

I have tried checking the Google archives and other websites. Are there any public versions of the spec that are still accessible ?

The ATM was put out-of-service until I figure this out. Quick help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.cencenelec.eu/areas-of-work/xfs_cwa16926_330_release/

You most likely will need/want the ATM specific documentation too as there are most likely exceptions to this specification that you need to know.

PS. This was literally the first google response for my search on "cen xfs 3.30" (Without the quotes).